# Why doesn't my function work using structures in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, structure

I am creating an array that contains the locations of sites in space. So for `array[2]`, I also want to say `array[2].num = 2` I want each site to have a unique site number `num` from 0 to N-1. Output different values of i for `array[i].num` gives 0, 1, 32767. Whereas, for increasing i, I want to see incrementing values from 0 to N-1.

I am very new to structures so if you could explain where I am making my mistakes I would much appreciate your help as a noice programmer.

```
 typedef struct site_t
{
    int num; // want to add more varaibels later hence type struct //
} site;
site fillStruct( site[], int);
int main()
{   int i;
    const int N = 20;
    site array[N];
    fillStruct(array, N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("location of site %d\n", array[i].num);
}
}

site fillStruct(site array[], int size) {
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {;
        array[k].num = k;   
        return array[k];
        } 

}
```

Comment: Why is there `return array[k];` which prevents the loop iterating? Only the first element is initialised

Comment: I have removed that, I only added that as there was a warning saying that it may reach end of non-void function.

Comment: `lattice[1].siteNum` outputs 32767 still and not 1 like I would want it to be.

Comment: That is because you have not initialised *any* of the array *except* `.siteNum` in the first element. Why would the code posted (even without that line) give such a warning? Is it the *actual* code you posted?

Comment: This code should not compile, on account of the `connections` member of `struct site_t` being declared with an incomplete type.  Accordingly, I'm not sure what to think of the apparent assertion that you're getting any output at all.

Comment: @WeatherVane Because there is no `return` statement after the loop. The compiler suspected if the loop condition is initially false.

Comment: @ArdentCoder there was before OP edited it out just now. To asmit98, please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete code that demonstrates the problem. That is, your actual code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: `connections` is in fact a flexible array member.  But that's unlikely to do what you want, especially given that you are constructing an array of these things and returning them by value.  Indeed, use of a FAM conceivably could be contributing to the very issue you are asking about, though there is no direct evidence of that in the code presently posted.

Comment: I have editted to contain hopefuly the standard required for the global programming audience to understand. Thanks

Comment: I just want to be able to get the array to go through my function and fill up the values of `array[i].num = i`, so if I am refering to array[2], the num = 2 for that entry.

Comment: The updated code still exits the function after initialising only the first member. I don't see why the function needs to return *any* value, it can be `void`.

Comment: The program now presented still contains the issue that @WeatherVane pointed out in the initial comment.  *Only the first array element is initialized by `fillStruct()`*, because the the loop body unconditionally executes a `return` statement.  Move the `return` out of the loop (and you'll then need to use something other than `k` for the index of the structure you want to return).

Comment: Ohhhh because its in the for loop

Comment: I want to return the function outside the for loop like so `return array[size]`?

Comment: BINGO, thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Please, for what *purpose* do you return a value? it isn't even used by the caller! Just make it a `void` function and delete the `return` statement.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to return one of the array elements at all.  I would just declare the function to return `void`, and not return anything.  But if you do return something then it cannot be `array[size]`, because the valid indexes for `array` are 0 ... size-1.

Comment: Fair enough, I have made it a void function and deleted the return, I am only 3 months experienced in programming so I had absolutely no reasoning as to why I did what I did. Thanks for questioning it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think your problem comes from your `fillStruct()` function. The loop in this function will only execute once, instead of N times. You never exceed k=0, so you set the `num` member for `array[0]` and then return `array[0]`.

When you return to your main function, you print the location for `array[0]` accurately, but subsequent site numbers in the array are just random uninitialized values.

Instead, you want the return statement to be outside of the loop block, so the function should like like...

```
site fillStruct(site array[], int size) {
    int k; 

    for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {;
        array[k].num = k;
    }

    return array[k-1]; // Returns the last site in the array
}
```

Now, when you return to your main function you will have 20 sites numbered 0 to 19 (for N=20).

Also note that in the code you gave, you are not using the return value of `fillStruct()`.

Hope that helps, let me know if I missed something.